# How can I select values within a list picker's child window using pywinauto?

Tags: pywinauto

I'd like to automate selection of specific items in a window with 2 child windows, one window for selecting the category and the other for showing the items inside the category.

The problem is how to select the values inside the child window as doing the ..print_control_indentifiers only give me the controls for the main window (filter field, display dict button and close button).

[window with 2 child windows (both named 'list picker')][1]

I got as far as setting focus to the child window on the left but couldn't extract the values in that window. Code below:

````
app = Application(backend='win32',allow_magic_lookup=True).connect(title='Dictionary Manager')

fileMenu = app.DictionaryManager.child_window(title="list picker", class_name="XNET$SysListView32", found_index=0).wrapper_object()
app.DictionaryManager.print_control_identifiers()
fileMenu.click_input()```


note: I've set the backend to 'win32' as setting to 'uia' generates an error for me.

How can this be done?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmxgs.png
````

Comment: Welcome! Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/help/formatting](/help/formatting) and also [/editing-help](/editing-help) for help on how to do so.